How do i loop through divs using jsoup in groovy script
My requirement is to scrape all the review data like reviewer name, date and comment in array. That i am doing in mulesoft in groovy script by importing Jsoup.
Using below query i am able to fetch the review data but it's coming in a single string. Not sure how to separate the div tag here.
how can i run a loop on <div class="Jwxk6d" and make the expected output?
code:
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup
    def url= "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.davdroid&hl=en_IN"
    def doc= Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    def appReviewData= doc.select("div[class='EGFGHd']").text()
    return [ReviewData: appReviewData]
    
    

expected output:
    {
        "ReviewData": [{
            "name": "Ben Perkins",
            "reviewDate": "7 June 2024",
            "reviewComment": "xyz"
        }]
    }


MuleSoft is a company name. Do you mean Mule 4.x? But there is nothing related to Mule or MuleSoft in the question. And what is the input for the expected output?

@aled this i am doing in mule 4. Someone who knows javascript or jquery can help here better. groovy script is mentioned for input and expected output is also mentioned.

The script can be run with Groovy command line so the question seems unrelated to Mule. Jsouo doesn't use jQuery. Where in the input on the question text is "Ben Perkins"?

@aled def url= "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.davdroid&hl=en_IN"  this is my input from where i need to scrap comment data. Opne the mentioned URL you can find all the comments, reviewer name details.

The question should not depend on an external resource that may change at any time. See in [mre]: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included as text in the question itself".

When I open the above url in my browser I don't see any comments and reviews. Also, the html does not contain any div with the class EGFGHd or Jwxk6d. Your code returns null for both classes.

This issue is on this line:
def appReviewData= doc.select("div[class='EGFGHd']").text()

The last .text() is returning the text content of the div which is a single String.  If you want to retain the structure of the DOM you would remove .text().  Of course that will leave you with the DOM nodes which isn't going to give you the output you desired.  So you'll need to write a quick loop to translate the DOM representation to your JSON you posted.  Something like this:
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup
    def url= "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.davdroid&hl=en_IN"
    def doc= Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    def appReviewData= doc.select(".EGFGHd").collect { dom ->
        return [
           name: dom.select('.X5PpBb').text(),
           reviewDate: dom.select('.bp9Aid').text(),
           reviewComment: dom.select('.h3YV2d').text()
        ]
    }
    return [ReviewData: appReviewData]

Also I simplified the class expression for the root div by just using .EGFGHd instead of the more verbose attribute syntax div[class="EGFGHd"].  If you want to narrow it down to only the div nodes with that class then you can do this div.EGFGHd.
That will do it.
